# Как изменить код, чтобы он возвращал количество итераций, выполненных циклом for?

Tags: python, for

```
   # Modify the code below to return the number of iterations the for-loop performed

def collatz(n): 
    initial = n
    print(initial)

    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        print( n )

    # if we got here, n must be 1
    print( "halted on input", initial )

print(collatz(17))
```

Comment: А где тут у вас for извините?

Comment: нужно поменять на for

Comment: функция возвращает числа, а нужно количество итераций

Comment: В данной реализации функция ничего не возвращает, только печатает что то на экран во время работы.

Comment: И зачем вам вообще на for что то менять? For перебирает последовательности, а у вас на входе 1 число.

Comment: да, вы правы она печатает, не возвращает, но мне нужно поститать количество итераций пока число не становится числом 1

Comment: может, превратить эти числа в список?

Answer (score 3):

Изменить на for не удастся, но количество итераций не проблема - вместо вашей части

```
while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    print( n )
```

примените

```
num_of_iter = 0
while n != 1:
    num_of_iter += 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    print( n )
```

и после окончания цикла будет в переменной `num_of_iter` количество итераций.

Comment: спасибо, это хороший вариант, я его уже рассматривала

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz(n): 
    initial = n
    print(initial) #напечатать исходное число, переданное в функцию
    count = 0 #добавьте счетчик итераций
    while n != 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        count +=1 #увеличивайте его значение на 1 каждую итерацию
    #print(count) #напечатайте на экран количество итераций
    return(count) #в задании у вас именно return указан
a = collatz(17)  #print тут не к чему
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда вам *действительно* нужен цикл `for`, не глядя на то, что он здесь неподходящий, вы можете применить `бесконечную` последовательность чисел из *генератора чисел*, например генератор `count()` из модуля [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools

def collatz(n): 
        initial = n
        print(initial)

        for num_iter in itertools.count(1):
            if n == 1:
                break
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n // 2
            else:
                n = 3 * n + 1
            print(n)

        print(f"Number of iterations: {num_iter}")
        print( "halted on input", initial )

print(collatz(17))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант с for и без использования библиотеки itertools, чистый Python:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(iter(int, 1), 1):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = 3 * n + 1
    print(n)
    if n == 1:
        break

print(i)
```